# Como faço para reiniciar a página caso o selenium não encontre o elemento na página?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
import time

url = 'https://google.com.br'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(10)


driver.find_element_by_class_name('gLFy').send_keys('Rodrigo')
print('Ok')
```

Preciso que dê um refresh na pagina quando não encontrar o elemento

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common import exceptions as ex

import time

url = 'https://google.com.br'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)

try:
    driver.find_element_by_class_name('gLFy').send_keys('Rodrigo')
    print('Ok')
except ex.NoSuchElementException:
    driver.refresh()
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente trocar o `find_element_by_class_name` pelo `find_element_by_xpath` usando assim:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='gLFyf gsfi']").send_keys('Rodrigo')
```

Comment: É que eu usei só como exemplo esse código, no caso eu estou automatizando downloads aí tem hora que a página não carrega por completo e tem que dar um refresh

Comment: e vc já tentou usar o `driver.refresh()` ?